# Where are "Class Actions" and "Class Outlets" in Xcode 6.4?

Tags: xcode, swift, interface-builder

I found an interesting tutorial on YouTube on how to create a Stop Watch app in Xcode ([you can watch it here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCu0DyJ9wcg)). In a certain spot, you have to drag an NSObject into Interface Builder and set it's Class Actions and Class Outlets. When I tried that, I could not find them. Does anybody know where the Class Outlets and Class Actions tabs are in Xcode? Thanks!

**PS-** I have Xcode 6.4, and the tutorial uses an earlier version. I think that maybe Class Actions and Outlets were put in a different location in later versions of Xcode.

**PPS-** I found several questions on Stack Overflow that were pretty much the same as mine, but the answers didn't make sense to me. Maybe someone can explain better?

[image]
Here is a screenshot. Does it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't find them because they no longer exist.

Years ago, Interface Builder was a separate app from Xcode.  You would use IB to edit your nib/xib, and it could generate .h and .m files for you.  You could define class actions and class outlets for it to put in those generated files.

When IB was merged into Xcode, that ability was removed.

The new way is to create your class in Xcode (File > New > File, and use the class template), which creates the .h and .m files for you (or a .swift file if you're using Swift).  Then you open your xib in the main editor, and the .h or .m or .swift file in the assistant editor (or vice versa). Now you can control-drag from and object in the xib to your .h or .m or .swift file and Xcode will offer to create an outlet or action for you.

[Here is some Apple documentation on the new technique.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-IB_connections/chapters/CreatingOutlet.html)

Comment: Thanks! I read it, and I figured out how to do it without Class Actions and Class Outlets. It's quite easy actually.